# unable to execute the ajax code

Tags: php, html, ajax, mysqli

im creating a php registration form using ajax, the below code that i have pasted isnt seems to be working , im literially new to this ajax concept
           when i click the register button it wont respond anything, and even in the database the values are not getting stored i have seached a lot for this ajax concept 
           but i don seem to get the result what i want please can any one help me where im actually going wrong please help me.

index.php

```
                    <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
                    <html>
                    <head>
                        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                        <script src="script.js"></script>
                    <style>
                    .error {
                        color:red;
                    }

                    .button {
                        background-color: #4CAF50;
                        border: none;
                        color: white;
                        padding: 10px 25px;
                        text-align: center;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        display: inline-block;
                        font-size: 16px;
                        margin: 4px 2px;
                        cursor: pointer;
                    }
                    .div1 {

                        margin-top: -19px;
                        margin-bottom: -25px;
                        margin-left: -19px; 
                    }

                    .copy {
                        border-radius: 4px;
                        padding: 6px 20px;
                       border-style: ridge;
                    }

                    .copy1{
                         border-radius: 4px;
                         padding: 6px 28px;
                         border-style: ridge;
                    }

                    .copy2{
                         border-radius: 4px;
                         padding: 4px 2px;

                    }
                    </style>
                    </head>
                    <body style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">  





                <?php
                // define variables and set to empty values
                include_once 'connect.php';

                $nameErr = $emailErr = $usernameErr = $passwordErr = $ageErr = "" ;
                $name = $email = $username = $password =  $age =  "";

                 if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
                  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                    $nameErr = "Name is required";
                  } else {
                    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                      $nameErr = "Only letters"; 
                    }
                  }

                   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                    $emailErr = "Email is required";
                  } else {
                    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
                    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
                    }
                  }

                  if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
                    $usernameErr = "Username is required";
                  } else {
                    $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
                     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$username)) {
                      $usernameErr = "Only letters"; 
                    }
                  }

                  if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
                    $passwordErr = "Password is required";
                  } else {
                    $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
                    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    // check weather password is alphanumeric
                  if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{6,}$/', $password))
                  {
                    $passwordErr = "Password must be alphanumeric and atleast 6 characters long!";
                  }
                  }



                    if (empty($_POST["age"])) {
                        $ageErr = "Age is required";
                    } 
                    elseif($_POST["age"]< 17 ) {
                        $ageErr = "Age should be above 18 years";
                    }
                    else {
                            $age = $_POST["age"];
                            }





                if($nameErr == "" && $emailErr == "" && $usernameErr == "" && $passwordErr == "" &&  $ageErr == "")
                  { 
                $check="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'";
                $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
                $da = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
                if($da[0] > 0) {
                    echo "Username Already in Exists<br/>";
                }

                else
                {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(`userid`,`username`, `password`, `email` , `name` , `age` )
                             VALUES ('','".$username."', '".$hashed_password."', '".$email."' , '".$name."' , '".$age."' )";

                        if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                        echo "Registered successfully";
                        } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
                        } 
                        mysqli_close($mysqli);
                }
                  }
                }

                function test_input($data) {
                  $data = trim($data);
                  $data = stripslashes($data);
                  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                  return $data;
                }
                ?>

                <div style="padding-left: 250px" class="div1">

                    <h2 style="color:#009999">Registration Form :</h2>
                    <p><span class="error">All fields are required </span></p>
                    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                            <span style="color:#0099ff">Name: </span>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class= "copy" style="margin-left: 52px"  value ="<?php 
                                     if (isset($name)) 
                                      echo $name; 
                                 ?>">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <span style="color:#0099ff"> E-mail: </span>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class= "copy" style="margin-left: 48px"  value ="<?php 
                                     if (isset($email)) 
                                      echo $email; 
                                 ?>">
                            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <span style="color:#0099ff"> Username: </span>
                            <input type="text" name="username"  class= "copy" style="margin-left:26px"  value ="<?php 
                                     if (isset($username)) 
                                      echo $username; 
                                 ?>">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $usernameErr;?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <span style="color:#0099ff"> Password: </span>
                            <input type="password" name="password"  class= "copy" style="margin-left:30px">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
                            <br><br>



                            <span style="color:#0099ff">  Age : </span>
                            <input type="number" name="age"  class= "copy" style="margin-left:62px"  value ="<?php 
                                     if (isset($age)) 
                                      echo $age; 
                                 ?>">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $ageErr;?></span>
                            <br><br>



                            <input type="button" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit">   


                        </form>
                </div>
                </body>


                </html>
```

script.js

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".submit").click(function(){
        var name = $("name").val();
        var email = $("email").val();
        var username = $("username").val();
        var password = $("password").val();
        var age = $("age").val();
        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email='+ email + '&username='+ username + '&password='+ password + '&age='+ age;
        var dataString = $("form").serialize();
        if(name==''|| email==''|| username==''|| password==''|| age=='')
        {

        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
        alert(result);
        }
        });
        }
        return false;
        });
        });
```

connect.php

```
        <?php


       $databaseHost = 'localhost';
       $databaseName = 'ajax1';
       $databaseUsername = 'root';
       $databasePassword = '';

       $mysqli = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName);

       ?>
```

Comment: Ajax post will work with key-value pairs. But your forming the query string.

Comment: sir what i should do to get it worked, im really new to this ajax concept

Comment: add id in submit button, or change the submit click with class also send the serialized form

Comment: sir can u please edit my code and let me know im trying what all suggestion m getting but unable to get my result please help me sir

Answer (score 0):

Update the submit button with submit class

```
<input type="button" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Update the js code with . insted of # // as # is for id

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
```

Also, use the form serialize

```
var dataString = $("form").serialize();
```

Php code change the submit to name

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
```

Comment: yes sir i checked some kind of pop up message is coming

Comment: Yes then it' working your ajax code is submit well, in the success you have added alert that is working, now you need to check the php code one by one

Comment: you need to submit proper name,email and age above the 18 as per your condition :)

Comment: what i should do sir next?

Comment: please can u guide me a little bit i don know what ajax properly

Comment: Okay you need to check and debug the php code, add echo at top of the code and exit 
like echo 'Here';exit; then check

Comment: sorry sir but im not getting what ur trying to tel me sir

Comment: what to do sir please help me .

Comment: Update the question with what you have tried till now

Comment: Have you changed the PHP code which I provide in my answer?

Comment: oops sorry sir but i have changed in my file

Comment: change in the question too

Comment: still i can see: if (isset($_POST['submit']))

Comment: how check it sir

Comment: can u please guide me sir

Comment: Check the network tab while submitting the form and show what is the result